# Exchange Server 2010 email encoding

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, encoding

We have just moved to exchange 2010 and have as400 sending emails, when the emails arrive (with french accents examples è é à ù ç) on OWA the accent letter is replaced with a question mark ?

example: D?ici ? votre d?part, l??

The same happens on both OWA & outlook exchange, I checked the source for the email on OWA and it shows charset=utf-8 but still doesnt appear to be showing correctly?

Would the code for the accents be getting stripped out before it hits the mailbox?

The source for the email received inside outlook was charset=us-ascii
If we email out to the internet (hotmail) directly from as400 for example, the email shows perfectly.

I have tried setting a mailbox to all different type of MIME, html, html + text etc etc but no change, am i right in thinking that as it arrives ok to an internet email account that it's our server not recognising the syntax for the accent and just removing it and adding a ?

any pointers would be brill

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should accept incoming emails as ISO-8859-1 encoded. Try this:

```
Get-RemoteDomain | Set-RemoteDomain -CharacterSet "ISO-8859-1" -NonMimeCharacterSet "ISO-8859-1"
```